# Mclust (GMM) graphics are too tiny (matrix of graohics)

Tags: r, gmm, mclust

It's just that I'm trying to know the number of clusters when I make use of GMM method in a dataset (specifically the dataset of asteroids of nasa) but I can't get to understand how to plot every graphic by themself and not in a matrix

For example in iris dataset https://programming.rhysshea.com/GMM_clustering/ (a matrix of graphics) but I want to watch to each individual graphic to understand what else I can do.

Also I want to make it like the examples and make my pc put colors for the points of each different cluster and not all of the same color

tbh I'm kind of lost here but I can't even advance if I can't plot correctly

```
set.seed(10) 
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(mclust)
columnas <-c("full_name", "spec_B", "neo", "pha","Danger")
asteroidesp2 <- na.omit(data_p2)
asteroidesp2 <- asteroidesp2[, ! names(asteroidesp2) %in% columnas, drop = F] 

asteroides.gmm <- Mclust(asteroides.scale, centers = 4)
plot(asteroides.gmm)
```